# WinForms GDI Rendering not repainting correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi

i have a simple WinForms app which paints some colored rectangles.
however when the window is resized it is not correctly updating.

[image]

already tried to overwrite OnResize

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
        repaintingMyStuffHere();
}
```

Comment: When the window is resized, a Paint event will occur. It seems the code you have in your paint handler (or the code that paints in your back buffer image) has wrong coordinates. Show a piece of the code that does the GDI+ calls.

Comment: [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?566658-RESOLVED-GDI-.-Resize-the-form-does-not-refresh-properly) may be help..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
     this.Invalidate();
     base.OnResize(e);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
{
     base.OnPaint(e);
     repaintingMyStuffHere(e.Graphics);
}
```

if you still have the problem try to set the folowing controlstyles:

```
public MyClass() {
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
                    ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
                    ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | 
                    ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
                    ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, 
                    true);
}
```

if you still have any problems please post your repaintingMyStuffHere methode.

Comment: Shouldn't resize invalidate anyway? At least the new parts of the window.

Comment: Resize invalidates if the Style ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw is set. By default the Style is set. But if you want to redraw only with some conditions you can remove the style and call this.Invalidate on your own. Are you creating a new Graphicscontext (this.CreateGraphics) in your methode or are you using the given from the OnPaint Event?

Answer (score 0):

To get your form/component to render property, and help improve performance, you would need to first override the `OnResize()` method to cause it to invalidate the form/component:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Then (optional, but recommended to reduce flickering) set the form/component `DoubleBuffered` property to true:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```